# answer to an "old" question: how to get it noticed?

Tags: support

Are there ways of attracting attention to a new answer - which you think worthwhile – to an old question?

Answer (score 3):

A new answer being posted on a question will automatically bump it up to the top of the front page anyway, since it is new activity.

If you wanted to bring attention to an extremely high quality answer that had just been posted on an older question you could also choose to bounty the question as "contains an exemplary answer" using your own reputation.

Comment: Ok, got it. I am not – yet – bold enough to deem one of my answers exemplary.

Comment: You cannot award a bounty to your own answer, but a bounty being offered will bring more eyes to your answer too.